# How do I know which jhipster version I am using?

Tags: jhipster

I need to duplicate a jhipster project. Since I have created this project I have updated jhipster versions. I want to duplicate the project with the same jhipster version of the first project.

How do I know which version of Jhipster I am using on my first application?

Answer (score 11):

Ask it jhipster directly, from within your project folder.

```
jhipster --version
```

Here's my  output

```
salathiel@salathiel-genese-pc:~/path/to/project$ jhipster --version
Using JHipster version installed locally in current project's node_modules
4.14.3
```

Comment: that works, but you can do it from anywhere, no need to be within the project folder

Comment: @BaDrAmer, did you notice the "on my first application" in his question? He wants the local/project version.

Answer (score 9):

The best place to find this information seems to be the first line of ./Gruntfile.js:

```js
// Generated on 2015-12-14 using generator-jhipster 2.25.0
```

The identifier of the version used to generate the project can be found in a number of other places as well:

```shell
➜   grep -R '2\.25\.0' . # current version of jhipster is 2.25.0

./Gruntfile.js:// Generated on 2015-12-14 using generator-jhipster 2.25.0
./node_modules/connect/History.md:2.25.0 / 2014-08-05
./node_modules/generator-jhipster/package.json:      "generator-jhipster@2.25.0",
./node_modules/generator-jhipster/package.json:  "_from": "generator-jhipster@2.25.0",
./node_modules/generator-jhipster/package.json:  "_id": "generator-jhipster@2.25.0",
./node_modules/generator-jhipster/package.json:    "raw": "generator-jhipster@2.25.0",
./node_modules/generator-jhipster/package.json:    "rawSpec": "2.25.0",
./node_modules/generator-jhipster/package.json:    "spec": "2.25.0",
./node_modules/generator-jhipster/package.json:  "_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/generator-jhipster/-/generator-jhipster-2.25.0.tgz",
./node_modules/generator-jhipster/package.json:  "_spec": "generator-jhipster@2.25.0",
./node_modules/generator-jhipster/package.json:    "tarball": "http://registry.npmjs.org/generator-jhipster/-/generator-jhipster-2.25.0.tgz"
./node_modules/generator-jhipster/package.json:  "version": "2.25.0"
./node_modules/phantomjs/node_modules/request/CHANGELOG.md:### v2.25.0 (2013/07/23 21:51 +00:00)
./node_modules/phantomjs/node_modules/request/CHANGELOG.md:- [828f12a](https://github.com/mikeal/request/commit/828f12a1ae0f187deee4d531b2eaf7531169aaf2) 2.25.0 (@mikeal)
./package.json:    "generator-jhipster": "2.25.0",
```

Comment: Thanks you. So if I want to use the version of Jhipster of my application (2.1.1) in order to create a new project, I can do : npm install -g generator-jhipster@2.1.1 and then generate my project?

Comment: Theoretically, I guess. I've just tried doing that and project creation failed with "Error: Cannot find module 'yeoman-environment'". You may be better off just biting the bullet and going with the current version of the generator just to make sure you don't get any dependency problems.

Answer (score 7):

When you run `yo jhipster` this is written in yellow in the welcome message.

Comment: This prints out the version installed on the system, not the version used to generate the project, though.

Answer (score 4):

If you have not used grunt during your applicaton setup, you can also find this information in the.yo-rc

"jhipsterVersion":xxx