# Can I change the concatenation character of the String-Array regarding JHipsters 'jhiTranslate'?

Tags: angular, jhipster, ngx-translate

If I use a string array for translation in e.g. i18n/en/home.json like

```
     "primaryIntroduction": {
         "p1": [
             "Then Jenkins triggers a task to connect to the docker-server",
             " and calls some docker- and docker-compose commands to pull the new image",
             " and rebuilds and restarts the docker-container."
         ]
    }
```

jhipster concatenates the `<p>` on the english page like:

> Then Jenkins triggers a task to connect to the
>   docker-server, and calls some docker- and docker-compose commands to
>   pull the new image, and rebuilds and restarts the docker-container.

(mind the commata)

Entering a new line without ending the line with a quotation mark, the json-file will brake.
Without newlines, bigger paragraphs are hard to read and to translate in my opinion.

Can I change the way the sentences are concatenated on myself? For example take a whitespace instead of a comma when putting the strings of the array together? Would it be useful to introduce a control-variable for that concatenation character in the Angular system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal, the value for your key `p1` is an array and the string representation of an array is a comma separated list. See https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/339 for details.

This issue was solved in ngx-translate by supporting [JSON5](https://json5.org/) format but unfortunately it has not been released yet and it seems the [project is no longer actively maintained](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/783) as last release is from november 2018.

So you could try the pipe suggestion to support arrays, see https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/339#issuecomment-360450296

Answer (score 0):

To change jhipster's Angular Translation Concatenation (Version 6.10.5, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34272375/7773582), I added

```
import { TranslateDefaultParser } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class TranslateAppParser extends TranslateDefaultParser {
  getValue(target: any, key: string): any {
    target = super.getValue(target, key);
    if (target instanceof Array) {
      target = target.join(' ');
    }
    return target;
  }
}
```

in `src/main/webapp/app/shared/translateappparser.module.ts`

and added

```
import {MissingTranslationHandler, TranslateLoader, TranslateModule, TranslateParser} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateAppParser } from 'app/shared/translateappparser.module';

export function createTranslateParser():any {
  return new TranslateAppParser();
}
```

as well as `parser: { provide: TranslateParser, useFactory: createTranslateParser },`

in

```
TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: translatePartialLoader,
        deps: [HttpClient],
      },
      parser: { provide: TranslateParser, useFactory: createTranslateParser },
      missingTranslationHandler: {
        provide: MissingTranslationHandler,
        useFactory: missingTranslationHandler,
        deps: [JhiConfigService],
      },
```

in file `src/main/webapp/app/core/core.module.ts`

That's exactly what [Gaël Marziou's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59219573/7773582) was pointing me to - today I just had to find the code snippets again while doing an jhipster-Upgrade with `jhipster --with-entities`