# Configuring point and comma decimals in Jhipster

Tags: jhipster

Let's say I have a Price field/atribute for an entity that I need to show with a point in the English version (9.5) and a comma in the Spanish version (9,5). Now, no matter in what language I select the app, it always shows the point . for the decimal

How can I change to comma decimal point in Jhipster?

Thanks

Comment: I think it's a preset of ngx-translate and if you can't use the `currency`-pipe in your code you have to override TranslateParse for your own like mentioned here: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/339#issuecomment-360450296. At least, it sounds comparable to my problem (including an answer worth reading) here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59214773/7773582.